# Additional, specific source and target for a Builder

Tags: scons

I'm new to Scons and I'm trying to figure out if I could use it for my use-case. I have a script whose main actoin is to take a single input and produces multiple output files in a given directory. However, it also needs one additional input and one additional output, as in

```
script --special-in some.foo --special-in some.bar input.foo output.dir/
```

The names of `some.*` files can be computed from the input file name (here `input.foo`). And the `some.*` files produced by one rule are consumed by other rules.

In the [documentation](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14754152) I found that one can create custom builders as in

```
bld = Builder(action = 'foobuild $TARGETS - $SOURCES',
              suffix = '.foo',
              src_suffix = '.input',
              emitter = modify_targets)
```

where the `emitter` adds the additional target and source. However, I couldn't find how should I distinguish the main source/target from the special ones, which need to be passed using specific options - I can't use `$TARGETS` and `$SOURCES` as in the above example. I could probably use a [generator](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14742400) and index into `source` and `target`, but this seems a bit hacky. I there a better way?

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you post an example (or several) of how your Builder call should look like ideally, and the command-line(s) that should result from it? In the example above I see only the input file, and "some.*" files which you claim to have covered basically. So I wonder where exactly your "special" options come into play...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you should be using both an emitter and a generator, just as you state at the end of your question.  The "main" source/target will be the first element in the source/target lists.  This doesn't seem hacky to me, but I may just be used to it...

Answers are always better with a working example...

Here is the SConstruct to do what you describe.  I'm not exactly sure how you plan to compute `some.foo` and `some.bar` from `input.foo`, so in this example I compute `input.bar` and `input.baz` from `input.foo`, and just append `output.dir` to the list of targets.

```
import os

def my_generator(source, target, env, for_signature):
    command = './script '
    command += ' '.join(['--special-in %s' % str(i) for i in source[1:]])
    command += ' '
    command += ' '.join([str(t) for t in target])
    return command

def my_emitter(target, source, env):
    source += ['%s%s' % (os.path.splitext(
        str(source[0]))[0], ext) for ext in ['.bar', '.baz']]
    target += ['output.dir']
    return target, source

bld = Builder(generator=my_generator,
              emitter=my_emitter)

env = Environment(BUILDERS={'Foo':bld})
env.Foo('output.foo', 'input.foo')
```

When run on linux...

```
>> touch input.bar input.baz input.foo

>> echo "#\!/bin/sh" > script && chmod +x script

>> tree
.
├── input.bar
├── input.baz
├── input.foo
├── SConstruct
└── script

0 directories, 5 files

>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
./script --special-in input.bar --special-in input.baz output.foo output.dir
scons: done building targets.
```

All dependencies/targets will be maintained, if you need to feed the outputs from one builder like this into another.

If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify what more you are trying to do.